# Get the content of a Sequelize Promise without executing it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

I know this could be a odd question, and I'm sorry since now for this.

Let's image I have something easy like this one.

```
let query = User.findAll({where: {name: 'something'}})
```

Is there a way that allows me to acces the content of `query`. And by *content* I mean the fact that is generated using `User.findAll`, I don't care about the result of the `.then()` of the promise.

Comment: Yes, all it will be, is object w/ `then` method

Comment: So I cannot get from the Promise the `User.findAll` information? I don't need the answer to that call, just the `Model` that generated the Promise

Comment: Not sure I 100% follow, but no, if you need reference to `User`, you cannot get it from the promise object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **options.logging** A function that gets executed while running the query to log the sql.

[Documentation Model.findAll](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)

Code:

```
const promise = User.findAll({
      logging: (query, obj) => {
        console.log("QUERY: ", query, "\n\nOBJ: ", obj);
      },
      where: {
        name: 'something',
      },
    });
```

Output:

```
QUERY:  Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users` AS `user` WHERE `user`.`name` = `something`;

OBJ:  { logging: [Function: logging],
  plain: false,
  raw: false,
  showWarnings: false,
  where: '`user`.`name` = `something`',
  hooks: true,
  rejectOnEmpty: false,
  attributes: [ 'id', 'name' ],
  tableNames: [ 'users' ],
  type: 'SELECT',
  model: user }
```

**UPDATED: [Reply for comment]**

I dont understood for what, but you can use something like this:

```
import DB from 'sequelize-connector';

// this is middleware
// app.use(this middleware)
export default (req, res) => {
  const promise = DB.user.findAll({
    logging: (query, obj) => {
      // here all your staff with req or res
      // get something from req
      // req.next()
      // or res.send(something)
      // or throw new Error ...
      req.next();
    },
    where: {
      id: 1,
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: This could be a cool solution, but that's not my case. I would like to keep the expressjs middleware architecture. I need the access to `req` and `res` objects. By the way this is the best solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for bringing up an old ticket, but there is a way to do this.

With `User` as your model:

```
sequelize.queryInterface.queryGenerator.selectQuery(
    User.getTableName(),
    // your typical options object:
    {
        attributes: ['id', 'col1', 'col2', 'etc'],
        where: {
            id: 1
        }
    },
    User
);
```

This directly returns a string of the generated query. Here is an example from a local database of mine, and I left out the `attributes` key to get all columns:

```
SELECT * FROM "public"."user" AS "User" WHERE "User"."id" = 1;
```